# The main thing is: how that binary for example 11110000 is divided into two parts such as s1=1111 and s2=0000. I have to do this in Java

Tags: java, binary, division

I have to input Text from the user then have to convert it into respective binary...The main thing is: how that binary for example 11110000 is divided into two parts such as s1=1111 and s2=0000. I have to do this in Java...HELP!

Comment: How this is related to python?

Comment: Please read the documentation of how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

First, read the string from keyboard

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String s1 = scanner.nextLine();
String s2 = scanner.nextLine();
```

Then, you have two steps. First, concatenate the two string to get one

```
 String s = s1 + s2;
```

And then, parse the value to create an integer. I assume you mean that you want to convert it to the respective decimal, since it's already binary. In that case

```
int result = Integer.parseInt(s, 2);
```

Comment: but i have a problem: how to get S1 and S2?